# Criar backup de aplicativo Django automaticamente

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, django-2.0

Desenvolvi um aplicativo web em Python e Django e preciso fazer o backup dos dados diariamente. Atualmente, utilizado o `Postgres` como SGBD.

Para realizar o backup descobri o módulo `django-dbbackup`, mas para usá-lo é necessário rodar o comando `python manage.py dbbackup`.

Como faço para gerar o backup automaticamente todos os dias em um determinado horário?